Fetching Specific Data from google Map to my Flutter Mobile APP
I have this project in class , I have to retrieve specific data from the Google Map . the thing I want is to get Pharmacies Near me , I want the steps to do that , because I tried ChatGPT and nothing is working for me , I know that I have to add the HTTP , Goelocator and Flutter maps configurations , but how to fetch that data is my problem.
ChatGPT Solution return to me a null value, like there is nothing in the data , I tried to check the code , line by line but unfortunately I couldn't

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
